# Android GridView DataBinding - ItemClickListener does not fire

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I've tried the following implementation for `GridView ItemClickListener`, the project are compiling fine, but when i clicks on `GridView` item, the `Toast` dont show my message, what's wrong ?

**Java Click handler**

```
public class MultiChoiceActions {

    public void onItemClick(View view, int position, List<FieldOption> objectList) {

        boolean currentValue = objectList.get(position).isChecked();
        objectList.get(position).setChecked(!currentValue);

        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "!currentValue " + (!currentValue) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**XML Layout EDITED**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="br.com.viewluck.viewmodel.MultiChoiceViewModel"/>

        <variable
            name="adapter"
            type="br.com.viewluck.viewmodel.MultiChoiceAdapter"/>

        <variable
            name="actions"
            type="br.com.viewluck.viewmodel.MultiChoiceActions"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{vm.fieldLabel}"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gd_multiple_choice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
            app:options="@{vm.objectList}"
            app:OnItemClickListener="@{(parent, view, position,id)->actions.onItemClick(view, position, vm.answer)}"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</layout>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Have you bind a listener with your xml?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya, updated the question, put the complete xml file.

Comment: @RaviRupareliya No, my mistake! Now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you might have forgot to bind it from activity/fragment

```
binding.setActions(listener)
```